# Google Data Studio OAuth Client Verification - what to show in our in-app testing video?

Tags: google-oauth, looker-studio

We're in the process of trying to get our Google Data Studio connectors' OAuth Client Verified and the process requires a video of the application in use (as per https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914), however the documentation mentions:

> Note that the video must clearly show the app's details such as the
>   app name, OAuth Client ID, etc. as applicable. The demo video must
>   show usage of sensitive and restricted scopes on each client.

But we are not in control of GDS, only our connectors. We only use the `/auth/script.external_request` scope to make calls to our own API.
What should we include in our video to show this information?

Reference:
[screengrab of the e-mail we received listing requirements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXCKm.png)

Answer (score 1):

This is a Google OAuth verification requirement. You should ideally reach out to the OAuth verification team for clarifications.

However, for the video, you can try just opening up Data Studio and installing your connector using the direct deployment link. Then you can create a data source using the connector and draw a table to demonstrate how data is fetched from your API using the `external_request` scope.